# Cannot Convert From 'Initializer List' to 'Char'

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void nullTest();

struct studentType
{
    char name[26];
    double gpa;
    int sID;
    char grade;
};

int main()
{
    studentType student;
    studentType* studentPtr;

    studentPtr = &student;


    student.gpa = 3.9;
    studentPtr->gpa = 3.9; // or (*studentPtr).gpa = 3.9;

//---> the error    studentPtr->name[26] = { 'M','a','r','k'};

return 0;
}
```

Hello I am not very sure what is wrong one way I went about fixing my error was converting it to strcpy_s and it would print ex: strcpy_s(studentPtr->name,"Mark"), but I was wondering if there was a better and or more efficent/natural way to fix this issue.

Comment: It's not possible to assign to arrays, only to *initialize* them (at definition) or to *copy* to them (as in `strcpy(studentPtr->name, "Mark")`. Using `strcpy` will also properly null-terminate your string.

Comment: Declare `name` to be a `std::string`, it will make your life easier.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: `studentPtr->name[26] = { 'M','a','r','k'};` your code is trying to initialize the single character that is one past the end of the name array with multiple characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the statement: `studentPtr->name[26] = { 'M','a','r','k'};`, you are accessing the 27th `char` in the array (which is out of bounds!) and trying to assign a `<braced-init_list>` to that single `char`.  That can never work.  But even if you were to remove the `[26]` from the assignment so that you are assigning to the array itself, that will still not work either, as you simply can't assign anything to a fixed array.  But, you can copy data into one, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct studentType
{
    char name[26];
    double gpa;
    int sID;
    char grade;
};

int main()
{
    studentType student;
    studentType* studentPtr;

    studentPtr = &student;

    student.gpa = 3.9;
    studentPtr->gpa = 3.9;

    strncpy(studentPtr->name, "Mark", 26);

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/yxYvBn)

Otherwise, use `std:::array<char, 26>` instead of `char[26]`, as `std::array` supports assignment:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

struct studentType
{
    array<char, 26> name;
    double gpa;
    int sID;
    char grade;
};

int main()
{
    studentType student;
    studentType* studentPtr;

    studentPtr = &student;


    student.gpa = 3.9;
    studentPtr->gpa = 3.9;

    studentPtr->name = {'M','a','r','k','\0'};

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mT7XoJ)

But really, you should be using `std::string` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct studentType
{
    string name;
    double gpa;
    int sID;
    char grade;
};

int main()
{
    studentType student;
    studentType* studentPtr;

    studentPtr = &student;


    student.gpa = 3.9;
    studentPtr->gpa = 3.9;

    studentPtr->name = "Mark";

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/41l46s)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void nullTest();

struct studentType
{
    char name[26];
    double gpa;
    int sID;
    char grade;
};

int main()
{
    studentType student;
    studentType* studentPtr;

    studentPtr = &student;


    student.gpa = 3.9;
    studentPtr->gpa = 3.9; // or (*studentPtr).gpa = 3.9;

    /*--> the change*/ strcpy_s(studentPtr->name, "Mark");

    cout << studentPtr << endl;
    cout << student.gpa << endl;
    cout << &student.gpa << endl;


    //nullTest();

    return 0;
}
```

This seems to be the suggestion to go for thanks for the help!